# Generics+FunctionalInterface compile in Eclipse and fail in javac

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, javac, functional-interface

I created the following class in Eclipse, but `javac` fails to compile it, however, I believe that ambiguity reported by `javac` can be resolved:

```
public class EclipseCompilerVsJavac {

    interface MyClass {
        Integer methodOverload(String a); // METHOD_1
        void methodOverload(String a, Integer b);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Fun1<P,R> {
        R invoke(P p);
    }
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Fun2<P1,P2,R> {
        R invoke(P1 p1, P2 p2);
    }

    static class R_m_P  {
    }

    <P, R> R call(Fun1<P, R> fun, P p, R_m_P signature) { // CALL_1
        return null;
    }
    <P1, P2, R> R call(Fun2<P1, P2, R> fun, P1 p1, P2 p2) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EclipseCompilerVsJavac example = new EclipseCompilerVsJavac();
        MyClass myClass=null;

        // !!! PROBLEMATIC LINE !!! 
        example.call(myClass::methodOverload, "a", new R_m_P());
    }    
}
```

In my opinion `CALL_1` is better match, therefore `METHOD_1` should be choosen. Is it `javac` bug, or `javac` follows specification and Eclipse uses information/guess it should not?

Javac error message:

> ... reference to call is ambiguous - both method call(Fun1,P,R_m_P)
>   EclipseCompilerVsJavac and method call(Fun2,P1,P2)
>   in EclipseCompilerVsJavac match

I use JDK 8 and Eclipse STS 3.63 + I know that there are different compilers. I want to know, whether my code is OK or not.

**UPDATE:**
Explanation:

- example.call/3 is invoked

  - 1st parameter: canNOT be used for decision - as call/3 methods reference both methodOverload variants
  - 2nd parameter: canNOT be used - both call/3 have generics there
  - 3rd parameter: should be used as R_m_P parameter is more specific than P2 generics

In other words, `CALL_1` should be chosen.

Comment: You are right - please ignore that comment. I wanted to try latest available JDK versions (after I tried official) and apart to Oracle JDK I downloaded also an early access release of OpenJDK (8u40).

Comment: I think that `void methodOverload(String a, Integer b)` isn't a match at all for the shape `(P1, P2) -> R` so `call(Fun2...)` shouldn't even be considered.